# PostgreSQL Crosstab Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table, case

How do I create crosstab queries in PostgreSQL? For example I have the following table:

```
Section    Status    Count
A          Active    1
A          Inactive  2
B          Active    4
B          Inactive  5
```

I would like the query to return the following crosstab:

```
Section    Active    Inactive
A          1         2
B          4         5
```

Comment: I had a slightly different structure and found this example a little hard to understand so I documented my way of thinking of this https://stackoverflow.com/q/49051959/808723. Maybe its helpful for anyone.

Answer (score 457, accepted):

Install the [additional module **`tablefunc`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) *once* per database, which provides the function `crosstab()`. Since Postgres 9.1 you can use [`CREATE EXTENSION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#TABLEFUNC-FUNCTIONS) for that:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;
```

#### Improved test case

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   section   text
 , status    text
 , ct        integer  -- "count" is a reserved word in standard SQL
);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES 
  ('A', 'Active', 1), ('A', 'Inactive', 2)
, ('B', 'Active', 4), ('B', 'Inactive', 5)
                    , ('C', 'Inactive', 7);  -- ('C', 'Active') is missing
```

#### Simple form - not fit for missing attributes

`crosstab(text)` with ***1*** input parameter:

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   'SELECT section, status, ct
    FROM   tbl
    ORDER  BY 1,2'  -- needs to be "ORDER BY 1,2" here
   ) AS ct ("Section" text, "Active" int, "Inactive" int);
```

Returns:

```
 Section | Active | Inactive
---------+--------+----------
 A       |      1 |        2
 B       |      4 |        5
 C       |      7 |           -- !!
```

- No need for casting and renaming.
- Note the **incorrect** result for `C`: the value `7` is filled in for the first column. Sometimes, this behavior is desirable, but not for this use case.
- The simple form is also limited to *exactly* three columns in the provided input query: *row_name*, *category*, *value*. There is no room for *extra columns* like in the 2-parameter alternative below.

#### Safe form

`crosstab(text, text)` with ***2*** input parameters:

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   'SELECT section, status, ct
    FROM   tbl
    ORDER  BY 1,2'  -- could also just be "ORDER BY 1" here

  , $$VALUES ('Active'::text), ('Inactive')$$
   ) AS ct ("Section" text, "Active" int, "Inactive" int);
```

Returns:

```
 Section | Active | Inactive
---------+--------+----------
 A       |      1 |        2
 B       |      4 |        5
 C       |        |        7  -- !!
```

- Note the correct result for `C`.
- The *second parameter* can be any query that returns one *row* per attribute matching the order of the column definition at the end. Often you will want to query distinct attributes from the underlying table like this:

  ```
    'SELECT DISTINCT attribute FROM tbl ORDER BY 1'
  ```

That's in the manual.

Since you have to spell out all columns in a column definition list anyway (except for pre-defined `crosstabN()` variants), it is typically more efficient to provide a short list in a `VALUES` expression like demonstrated:

```
    $$VALUES ('Active'::text), ('Inactive')$$)
```

Or (not in the manual):

```
    $$SELECT unnest('{Active,Inactive}'::text[])$$  -- short syntax for long lists
```

- I used [**dollar quoting**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) to make quoting easier.
- You can even output columns with ***different* data types** with `crosstab(text, text)` - as long as the text representation of the value column is valid input for the target type. This way you might have attributes of different kind and output `text`, `date`, `numeric` etc. for respective attributes. There is a code example at the end of the [chapter *`crosstab(text, text)`* in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#id-1.11.7.47.4.7).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c18b08e0e522556d486634d066a9d122)*

#### Effect of excess input rows

Excess input rows are handled differently - duplicate rows for the same ("row_name", "category") combination - `(section, status)` in the above example.

The **1-parameter** form fills in available value columns from left to right. Excess values are discarded.
**Earlier input rows win.**

The **2-parameter** form assigns each input value to its dedicated column, overwriting any previous assignment.
**Later input rows win.**

Typically, you don't have duplicates to begin with. But if you do, carefully adjust the sort order to your requirements - and document what's happening.
Or get fast arbitrary results if you don't care. Just be aware of the effect.

#### Advanced examples

- [Pivot on Multiple Columns using Tablefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc/15421607#15421607) - also demonstrating mentioned "extra columns"
- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)

#### `\crosstabview` in psql

Postgres **9.6** added this meta-command to its default interactive terminal [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). You can run the query you would use as first `crosstab()` parameter and feed it to `\crosstabview` (immediately or in the next step). Like:

```
db=> SELECT section, status, ct FROM tbl \crosstabview
```

Similar result as above, but it's a *representation feature on the client side* exclusively. Input rows are treated slightly differently, hence `ORDER BY` is not required. Details for [`\crosstabview` in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-CROSSTABVIEW) There are more code examples at the bottom of that page.

Related answer on dba.SE by Daniel Vérité (the author of the psql feature):

- [How do I generate a pivoted CROSS JOIN where the resulting table definition is unknown?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159286/3684)

Comment: +1, good writeup, thanks for noticing `In practice the SQL query should always specify ORDER BY 1,2 to ensure that the input rows are properly ordered`

Comment: I've some problems using $$VALUES .. $$. 
I've used instead 'VALUES (''<attr>'':: <type>), .. '

Comment: Can we specify parameter binding in crosstab query ?  I am getting this error => could not determine data type of parameter $2

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter This is another example of you explaining complicated things in an extremely competent, thoughtful and easy to grasp way. If there were a nobel price for helping on stack overflow you should get it

Comment: _, $$VALUES ('Active'::text), ('Inactive')$$_ Why does 'Active' have a cast to text and 'Inactive' does not?

Comment: @AndreSilva: All rows of the same set must have the same column types. It's enough to cast explicitly in *one* row, and the rest will fall in line. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30204394/939860; https://stackoverflow.com/a/12427434/939860

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing out that $$ quoting can be used to keep the inner sql 'independently executable' with tools like dbeaver (by selecting the inner sql text only); not to mention keeping any colour coding the editor provides for sql.

Comment: I searched the internet for a reason why my pivoting wasn't working properly and none of the answers would make my pivot function correctly except this one. Extra points for having a SQL fiddle that I was able to adapt to my specific needs to figure out the issue I was having!

Answer (score 42):

```
SELECT section,
       SUM(CASE status WHEN 'Active'   THEN count ELSE 0 END) AS active,  --here you pivot each status value as a separate column explicitly
       SUM(CASE status WHEN 'Inactive' THEN count ELSE 0 END) AS inactive --here you pivot each status value as a separate column explicitly

FROM t
GROUP BY section
```

Comment: Can someone explain what the crosstab function in the tablefunc module adds to this answer, which both does the job at hand, and to my mind is easier to understand?

Comment: @JohnBarça: A simple case like this can easily be solved with CASE statements. However, this gets unwieldy very quickly with more attributes and / or other data types than just integers. As an aside: this form uses the aggregate function `sum()`, it would be better to use `min()` or `max()` and no `ELSE` which works for `text` also. But this has subtly different effects than `corosstab()`, which only uses the "first" value per attribute. Doesn't matter as long as there can only be one. Finally, performance is relevant, too. `crosstab()` is written in C and optimized for the task.

Comment: Consider adding explaination vs just a block of code

Comment: In my postgresql for some reason tablefunc and crosstab are not defined, and I am not permitted to define them. This intuitive solution worked for me, so thums up!

Answer (score 35):

You can use the `crosstab()` function of the [additional module `tablefunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) - which you have to install *once* per database. Since PostgreSQL 9.1 you can use [`CREATE EXTENSION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createextension.html) for that:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

In your case, I believe it would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t (Section CHAR(1), Status VARCHAR(10), Count integer);

INSERT INTO t VALUES ('A', 'Active',   1);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('A', 'Inactive', 2);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('B', 'Active',   4);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('B', 'Inactive', 5);

SELECT row_name AS Section,
       category_1::integer AS Active,
       category_2::integer AS Inactive
FROM crosstab('select section::text, status, count::text from t',2)
            AS ct (row_name text, category_1 text, category_2 text);
```

DB Fiddle here:

- Everything works: https://dbfiddle.uk/iKCW9Uhh
- Without `CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;` you get this error: https://dbfiddle.uk/j8W1CMvI

  ```
  ERROR:  function crosstab(unknown, integer) does not exist
  LINE 4: FROM crosstab('select section::text, status, count::text fro...
               ^
  HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  ```

Comment: In case you use a parameter in the crosstab query, you have to escape it properly. Example: (from above) say you want only the active ones: SELECT ... FROM crosstab('select section::text, status, count::text from t where status=''active''', 2) AS ... (notice the double quotes). In case the parameter is passed at runtime by the user (as a function parameter for example) you can say: SELECT ... FROM crosstab('select section::text, status, count::text from t where status=''' || par_active || '''', 2) AS ... (triple quotes here!). In BIRT this also works with the ? placeholder.

Answer (score 14):

Solution with JSON aggregation:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (
  section   text
, status    text
, ct        integer  -- don't use "count" as column name.
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES 
  ('A', 'Active', 1), ('A', 'Inactive', 2)
, ('B', 'Active', 4), ('B', 'Inactive', 5)
                   , ('C', 'Inactive', 7); 


SELECT section,
       (obj ->> 'Active')::int AS active,
       (obj ->> 'Inactive')::int AS inactive
FROM (SELECT section, json_object_agg(status,ct) AS obj
      FROM t
      GROUP BY section
     )X
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this isn't complete because I can't test it here, but it may get you off in the right direction.  I'm translating from something I use that makes a similar query:

```
select mt.section, mt1.count as Active, mt2.count as Inactive
from mytable mt
left join (select section, count from mytable where status='Active')mt1
on mt.section = mt1.section
left join (select section, count from mytable where status='Inactive')mt2
on mt.section = mt2.section
group by mt.section,
         mt1.count,
         mt2.count
order by mt.section asc;
```

The code I'm working from is:

```
select m.typeID, m1.highBid, m2.lowAsk, m1.highBid - m2.lowAsk as diff, 100*(m1.highBid - m2.lowAsk)/m2.lowAsk as diffPercent
from mktTrades m
   left join (select typeID,MAX(price) as highBid from mktTrades where bid=1 group by typeID)m1
   on m.typeID = m1.typeID
   left join (select typeID,MIN(price) as lowAsk  from mktTrades where bid=0 group by typeID)m2
   on m1.typeID = m2.typeID
group by m.typeID, 
         m1.highBid, 
         m2.lowAsk
order by diffPercent desc;
```

which will return a typeID, the highest price bid and the lowest price asked and the difference between the two (a positive difference would mean something could be bought for less than it can be sold).

Comment: You're missing a from clause, otherwise this is correct.

The explain plans are wildly different on my system - the crosstab function has a cost of 22.5 while the LEFT JOIN approach is about 4 times as expensive with a cost of 91.38. It also produces about twice as many physical reads and performs hash joins - which can be quite expensive compared to other join types.

Answer (score 0):

`Crosstab` function is available under the `tablefunc` extension. You'll have to create this extension one time for the database.

CREATE EXTENSION `tablefunc`;

*You can use the below code to create pivot table using cross tab:*

```
create table test_Crosstab( section text,
status text,
count numeric)

insert into test_Crosstab values ( 'A','Active',1)
                ,( 'A','Inactive',2)
                ,( 'B','Active',4)
                ,( 'B','Inactive',5)

select * from crosstab(
    'select section
    ,status
    ,count
    from test_crosstab'
    )as ctab ("Section" text,"Active" numeric,"Inactive" numeric)
```

Comment: This answer adds nothing over pre-existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

There's a different dynamic method that I've devised, one that employs a dynamic rec. type (a temp table, built via an anonymous procedure) & JSON. This may be useful for an end-user who can't install the tablefunc/crosstab extension, but can still create temp tables or run anon. proc's.

The example assumes all the xtab columns are the same type (INTEGER), but the # of columns is data-driven & variadic. That said, JSON aggregate functions do allow for mixed data types, so there's potential for innovation via the use of embedded composite (mixed) types.

The real meat of it can be reduced down to one step if you want to statically define the rec. type inside the JSON recordset function (via nested SELECTs that emit a composite type).

[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/N1EzugHk)

https://dbfiddle.uk/N1EzugHk